# css file on googlecode charset issue with TortoiseSVN

Tags: css, character-encoding, tortoisesvn, hebrew, google-code

I have a css file containing hebrew characters:

```
.className:after {
     content: "x סגור";
}
```

The file is stored on googlecode SVN; When viewing this file in the browser I see `????` instead of what is expected.

I tried adding `@charset` at the top of the file as well as setting TortoiseSVN `mime-type` properties `svn:charset` to `utf-8` etc

When the same CSS is inside the html files, it renders great.

I assume this is the way the TortoiseSVN stores the file or how google is serving the file.

I've tried a few solutions as suggested here before, e.g. [Specifying a charset for stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661399/specifying-a-charset-for-stylesheets), but none seems to solve my issue.

Comment: If other developers can check out this file, then it's not a big problem. Maybe googlecode's source browser doesn't understand utf8, but that's a minor thing. Do you have a link to that page?