# Unicode character, down triangle, shows up as strange text

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, utf-8, ascii

I have a webpage on which I'm using a unicode down triangle on buttons to indicate that selecting those buttons will display a drop-down.

I'm adding the triangles in css thusly:

```css
    .icon:after {
        content:"▼";
    }
    .icon {
        width:12px;
        height:12px;
        margin: 3px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor:default;
    }
```

The meta tags in the page are:

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; chrome=1" >
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

However, the triangles don't show up as triangles, they show up like this: [image: strange text instead of unicode character]

Any idea why it might be showing up like this and how to fix it?

Comment: This is clearly a file encoding issue. You can avoid it by just using `content:"\25bc";`

Comment: @RaymondChen is that supported across all browsers?

Comment: I'll leave you to research that. You have to do some of the work, too.

Comment: @RaymondChen alternatively, you could put that in an answer, with an explanation, and then I could accept it if it works

Comment: Here is a nice site for [Useful UTF-8 Characters](http://mcdlr.com/8/) with `CSS Escape` and also read [this article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/).

Comment: If your CSS file is external, it should be served with the correct charset -- in the MIME type or `@charset` rule or both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shape all kind of chars using any kind of unicode character.
In your case for example you just have to use something like:

```
.icon:after {
    content:"\25bc";
}
```

or for a small triangle:

```
.icon:after {
    content:"\25be";
}
```

This trick it's fully cross browser compatible.

Comment: Any idea why mine isn't showing up just copying the character?

Comment: The reason is that CSS needs to be written using only ASCII chars. You can get a look here if you'd like to use non-ASCII as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526033/why-specify-charset-utf-8-in-your-css-file

Answer (score 2):

The document (HTML or CSS document) in which the CSS rule appears is sent with HTTP headers that specify an encoding other than UTF-8, probably ISO-8859-1 or windows-1252, or, in the case of a CSS document, do not specify the encoding at all, making browsers guess.

The solution is to fix this by changing the HTTP headers. See the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset.en.php).

If HTTP headers do not specify the encoding, *then* charset declarations inside the document itself may take effect.

Using character escapes may help to remove the symptoms, but to avoid future problems (when someone adds an odd character into a document), it is best to get the encoding problem fixed.