# CSS Page Centering

Tags: css, center, conflict

I'm not sure where my code is messed up, but I'm trying to get my code to center.  Here is what I have so far:

The problem that I am running into is that the page won't actually center.  When it loads, the left margin is only a 10px.  I'm sure there is a conflict somewhere, or I just borked something, and I've been searching for hours now, and have found nothing.  Here is the following code:

```
body {
background-color: #12121D;
}   

#contain {
display: block;
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.version{
text-align:right;
font-family: Calibri, sans-serif, serif;
text-decoration:none;
color:#00F;
}

#header {
width: 1000px;
height: 230px;
    }

#logo {
width: 600px;
margin: 50px 0px 0px 10px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
  }

#banner {
text-align: right;
float: right;
z-index: -1;
    }

#menu {
height: 80px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#main {
height: 500px;
width: 850px;
margin-left: 75px;
/*position: absolute;*/
z-index: 4;
/*float: left*/;
  }

#content {
width: 850px;
height: 500px;
float: left;
margin-left: 0px;
     }
```

And the html follows as:

```
<body>
<div id="contain">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"> <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
        <br />
        <a class="version" href="JavaScript:changeSheets(1)">View       Mobile<a/>
        </div>
        <div id="banner"><img src="images/banner.png" alt="banner"/></div>
    </div>
<div id="menu">
    <div class="pages">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Front Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="releases.html">Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="author.html">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Info</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="why" id="whyBackground"> <img src="images/reviewsites.png" alt="reviewsites"/>
            <h1>Why am I doing this?</h1>
            <br />
            Insert text here
            <h1>What is my goal?</h1>
            Insert text here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It'd help if you had a working JSFiddle

Comment: Looks centered to me: http://jsbin.com/atazaf/1

Comment: #contain is 1000px. What's your browser/screen size currently? (I know, probably a dumb question, but who knows?)

Comment: @Terry Young- 1920x1080

Comment: Yours will look different. We don't have the sources for your images, etc. So it won't display the same.

Comment: @TerryYoung Here is the link to my current code: http://jsbin.com/itiwez/2/edit

I just can't get it to center.

Comment: I removed `@charset "utf-8"` in your CSS and it instantly worked (at least in your jsbin demo). Is your CSS file actually in UTF-8 format?

Comment: Answer fit for acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is Your code:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/w9Zgc/2/
```

On my screen larger 1920px page is centered. I think that you have screen resolution close to 1024px width so than left margin left equal 10px is quite reasonable. Another advice is to reset padding and margin of body

```
body, html {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is my entire code (with edits): http://jsbin.com/itiwez/1/edit

If I take the code I posted earlier, some people have it centering.  So it must be something that I've added outside of what I posted here.  Any help (and the help you've provided) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

One thing that will help you center a div is to specify the width, and then set the right & left margins to auto:

```
#main{
   width: 850px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: He already had `margin: 0 auto;`, which should already set left and right margins to `auto`

Answer (score -1):

Judging from your link at http://jsbin.com/itiwez/2/edit

I removed `@charset "utf-8"` in your CSS and it instantly worked (at least in your jsbin demo). Is your CSS file actually in UTF-8 format?

FYI: [Why specify @charset "UTF-8"; in your CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526033/why-specify-charset-utf-8-in-your-css-file)

Comment: And thank yourself for your own effort in presenting the issue. So I assume my answer is correct?