# css not linking to Html encoding issue

Tags: html, file, encoding, utf-16le

I have a file with HTML with UTF-16 LE encoding, the issue is CSS file is not linking to HTML

I copy all content in the HTML file to a new HTML file, it works fine.

After several attempts to understand the issue, I came to know the file is encoded with UTF-16 LE, but how encoding change the functionality and at the same time the file looks fine and it also rendering in chrome with all good characters.

My question is how encoding change the functionality?

Comment: Have you tried adding `@charset`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why specify @charset "UTF-8"; in your CSS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526033/why-specify-charset-utf-8-in-your-css-file)